# Use a FET to switch 60 A LED current by microcontroller without voltage drop?

Tags: power, led, switching

The project is a LED light bar consisting of:
20x Li Ion 21700 batteries in parallel (3.5 ... 4.2 V, 100 Ah) as power source (direct without any step up or step down converter),

1600 LEDs (individually addressable), total max current about 60 A,

ESP32 microcontroller running WLED software, controlling the LEDs.

Since the 1600 LEDs have a quite high quiescent current even when all leds switched off, I need a solution to switch the supply power (max 60 A).
Since the battery voltage under high load is already in the limits of the LED specs (3.5 V is LED minimum voltage), I see the problem when using a FET that there will be a voltage drop which can cause trouble going under 3.5 V.
What could be the solution (2 or more FETs in parallel, or certain FET that has nearly no voltage drop?) at 60 A? Or a big high amps car relay?

The uC logic output is 3.3 V.

Comment: How much voltage drop can you tolerate at 60A? Find a FET with Rdson with specs to match at given temperature + some margin

Comment: It's a number game; you need to supply numbers.

Comment: I would use a relay - i guess the power rail is not switched that often. Relays tend to have lower resistance and better power handling ability. You could use SPST types (sometime there are two circuits in one package) in parallel without any problems.

Comment: Also, a big capacitor and smaller, faster ones, before the FET to handle the surges, wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Use a battery with at least 6 V and a buck converter with enable. Or even a 48 V battery and a converter using a transformer. (Even if&when you can switch such loads, wiring may drop more millivolts than "WLED" will tolerate.)

Comment: Lija Andy said, give more detail, to get more detail (LED type, how much mV headroom are there?).

Comment: The LEDs are SK6812 addressable LEDs (RGBW) and 3,5V is the lowest voltage where the logic inside the led will work. The Battery voltage will be at least 3,6V at 50 amps for up to 50% of the batt capacity, which is enough for the application. There is only little room so its not possible to wire the batt in serial and use a DC/DC or transformer for that high amps. As said, about 100mV room for voltage drop to use a FET. Which means when switching the 3,6V over FETs there must be a resulting voltage of 3,5 at 50 or 60 amps.

Comment: battery type must be li ion single cell in parallel, so no option for other voltage. Temperature is 20-25 C room temperature

Comment: You can get hold of 1 milliohm MOSFETs

Comment: Yes I know and all of them will have a huge voltage drop at 50A

Comment: @markus_e A 1mΩ MOSFET will have 50mV drop at 50A. Maybe 75mV at high temperature. That's not what I'd call 'huge'. You do need to drive the gate with enough voltage (probably 10V+) so a DC-DC converter and to drive it on and off quickly (so some kind of gate driver, DIY or a chip). It might be more convenient if the load is split up to use multiple MOSFETs though.

Comment: ok sounds good, I found vishay sum40014M and try that. maybe even with 3.6v Vgs and in worst case with a higher voltage - I will split into to halfs which makes it a bit easier, also for a part of the wire's sizes. thank you

Comment: Suggestion: Hell bent on actually powering those 1600 *RGBW SK6812* "pixels", wire them up, in modules, preferably (if not using prefab strips). Assemble the cells in packs of 4-5 cells. Wire everything up to get half of the pixels shining bright. Measure the voltage at the pixel farthest from the cells electrically and see whether you are still within specifications of the SK6812 (3.5 V is "absolute minimum", with 5.2 V typical).

Comment: (`battery type must be li ion single cell in parallel` *WHY*? What is the perceived advantage of 1S20P over, say, 4S5P?)

Comment: the LEDs are stripes (144/meter) and powered from both ends in a 1.6m length. It is a cylindrical acrylic pole with 44mm inside diameter, the space I have for batteries and electronics is 27 mm diameter. therefore, having a system voltage of 14V in a 4S config results in the need of quite big dc/dc converters handling 250W of power... I have no room for it... and also would require a BMS for charging

Comment: I tried to create [a chat room about this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142338/powering-a-60-a-low-voltage-load-from-a-battery-in-restricted-space).